# loadHtml instead of loadUrl in atom-shell? (trying to use jade)

Tags: pug, electron

atom-shell only has a method to load HTML from a URL

```
window.loadUrl('file://...')
```

But I want to use Jade

```
var html = jade.renderFile('file://...');
```

Is there a way to use the compiled `html` in atom-shell `window`? Something like `loadHtml(html)`?

I suppose I could run an express server that serves compiled html but that would be rather inefficient..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a mac:

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args 'data:text/html,<html><body><h1>title</h1><p>text</p></body></html>'
```

Details about URI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Comment: It worked, thanks! `window.loadUrl('data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(jade.renderFile('file://...')))`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the executeJavaScript function with something like

```
mainWindow.loadUrl('about:blank');
var s = '<DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Written!</title></head><body><h1>Hello!</h1></body></html>';
mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('document.write("' + s + '");');
```